# error parsing UTF-8 params in Django app at Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, utf-8

I have a django project running on Heroku dyno. The problem is that when I pass a query params in UTF-8 language (farsi) I got 500 error with this log message.

```
2022-01-12T22:11:30.432160+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/memes/?search=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA" host=amindjangofirst.herokuapp.com request_id=dece8cd8-8a8e-489e-801a-6b1cbc3df270 fwd="184.163.35.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=83ms status=500 bytes=452 protocol=https
2022-01-12T22:11:30.431992+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.24.50 - - [12/Jan/2022:22:11:30 +0000] "GET /api/memes/?search=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://amindjangofirst.herokuapp.com/api/memes/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15"
```

but if I use english characters in query everything works well also on my local machine it's working with UTF-8 params

api is available at:

working => https://amindjangofirst.herokuapp.com/api/memes/?search=test

not-working => [https://amindjangofirst.herokuapp.com/api/memes/?search=تست](https://amindjangofirst.herokuapp.com/api/memes/?search=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA)

Answer (score 0):

I foud the problem

The database that I used was not in UTF-8 encoding
just change the database to utf-8 and then everything working